# How to port android application to samsung sdk using adt eclipse?

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

i want to port my android application to samsung sdk using adt eclipse.How to do it?
I refered below link
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000182